# Unable to synchronize resource src to server:ClassCastException

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I am following this tutorial for setting [google toolkit](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Google_Data_APIs_Toolkit_Setup) for salesforce org when I reach 
Synchronizing with your Force.com Developer Edition org
and i synchronize it with my developer org suddenly a dialog error occurred with info:

Unable to synchronize resource src to server:ClassCastException:com.salesforce.ide.api.metadata.types.MetaData$JaxbAccessorF_full_Name can not be cast to com.sun.xml.Internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor

Reason:
com.salesforce.ide.api.metadata.types.Metadata$JaxbAccessorF_full_Name cannot be cast to com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor

How to resolve this error any one g0t through this error then please help to resolve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using jdk7 install java runtime enviorment6 and error is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Running the Force.com IDE as Administrator can also work.